# Prolog, Read data from CSV with different separator

Tags: csv, prolog, swi-prolog

I need to read different CSV file in prolog, some row are formatted with `0'\t`, in other file are formatted with the space `0'`.

I used:

```
    read_points(Filename, Points) :-
       csv_read_file(Filename, P,[convert(true),functor(pt),separator(0'\t)]),
       csv_read_file(Filename, P,[convert(true),functor(pt),separator(0' )]).
```

But it dosen't work because return me two different list.

How can I code it correctley?
Thank you.

EDIT:
example file with `'0\t`:

```
0.1     5
3       5
5       8
```

example with `'0`:

```
0.1 5
3 5
5 8
```

Comment: Could you show an example of a line from each of your different kinds of CSV files?

Comment: i have updated the question.
the first example is made with TAB key, the second with the space bar only.

Comment: So really what you're wanting to do is have a single predicate that will figure out whether the file is using a space or a tab and return the list accordingly? Because the individual `csv_read_file` calls as you show them work fine on the corresponding correct file. Unfortunately, once you instantiate the list, `P`, then it cannot be re-instantiated. You'll need to add logic to examine the file for what delimiter it uses, if you're trying to make it automatic.

Comment: Yes, individually the predicate csv_read_file work fine, but i need to create a single predicate that work independently by the file that i use, but i don't know how. i tired with 'or' but return me two list P.

Comment: As I mentioned, you either (a) need to know in advance what delimiter each file uses and call a *different* predicate for each with a different delimiter, or (b) you'll need to write some code that examines the file to see what delimiter it has. Both kinds of files will succeed in parsing no matter what delimiter you use since the absence of a delimiter is not considered an error in CSV, but rather a file consisting of lines that represent one single field. If you have any files that have fields with spaces but use tab delimiter, that's going to be nearly impossible to distinguish.

Comment: @lurker i post a solution, it works, tahnk you. it is what are you talking about? do you think there is a better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolve it using the If statement and searching in the first line if there is a space or not.

```
read(Filename, Elements) :-
(   space(Filename)
->   csv_read_file(Filename, L,[functor(line),separator(0' )])
;   csv_read_file(Filename, L,[functor(line),separator(0'\t)])
).

space(File):-
  read_first(File,L),
  once(member(32,L)).

read_first(File, sol) :-
  see(File),
  read_one_line(Codes),
  seen,
  Sol = Codes.

read_one_line(Codes) :-
  get0(Code),
  (   Code < 0 /* end of file */ ->
      Codes = []
  ;   Code =:= 10 /* end of line */ ->
      Codes = []
  ;   Codes = [Code|Codes1],
      read_one_line(Codes1)
  ).
```

Comment: My only concern with this solution, which I raised in my comment, is that in a file with tab separated fields, you could have a field value which contains a space in which case `space/1` will give an incorrect result. So your solution must assume that there are no spaces in field values for tab-separated fields.

Comment: Yes, there si only two type Of file, tab o space file in my exercise and solution! Not mixed file. But it's possibile to change the code to check line by line before to reed!